# How to multiply element-wise two tensors with partially matching dimensions?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Say I have two tensors, tensor A with Size [16] and tensor B with size [16,1,30,30].

I want to multiply them element-wise.

The following code works, but I was wondering if there is another way:

```
result = A[..., None, None, None] * B
```

perhaps something which looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the view method and broadcasting:

```
result = A.view(16, 1, 1, 1) * B
```

The view method creates a tensor with shape **[ [[[a_1]]], [[[a_2]]], ..., [[[a_16]]] ]**. Then broadcasting takes effect during the multiplication.

Example:

> A = [1,2,3] (shape = (3,) )
>
> B =
> [[[1,1],[1,1]],
> [[1,1],[1,1]],
> [[1,1],[1,1]]] (shape = (3,2,2) )
>
> A.view(3,1,1)*B ->
> [[[1,1],[1,1]],
> [[2,2],[2,2]],
> [[3,3],[3,3]]] (shape = (3,2,2) )